# calculate indegree centralization of graph with python networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a graph and want to calculate its indegree and outdegree centralization. I tried to do this by using `python networkx`, but there I can only find a method to calculate indegree and outdegree centrality for each node. Is there a way to calculate in- and outdegree centralization of a graph in `networkx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code.  I'm assuming that in-degree centralization is defined as I describe below...

```
N=G.order()
indegrees = G.in_degree().values()
max_in = max(indegrees)
centralization = float((N*max_in - sum(indegrees)))/(N-1)**2
```

Note I've written this with the assumption that it's python 2, not 3.  So I've used `float` in the division.  You can adapt as needed.

---

**begin definition**

Given a network `G`, define let `y` be the node with the largest in-degree, and use `d_i(u)` to denote the in-degree of a node `u`.  Define `H_G` to be (I don't know a better way to write mathematical formulae on stackoverflow - would appreciate anyone who knows to either edit this or give a comment)

```
H_G = \sum_{u} d_i(y) - d_i(u)  
    =  N d_i(u) - \sum_u d_i(u)
```

where `u` iterates over all nodes in `G` and `N` is the number of nodes of `G`.

The maximum possible value for a graph on `N` nodes comes when there is a single node to which all other nodes point to and no other nodes have edges to them.  Then this `H_G` is `(N-1)^2`.

So for a given network, we define the centralization to be it's value of `H_G` compared to the maximum.  So `C(G) = H_G/ (N-1)^2`.

**end definition**

Comment: Is this Freeman's indegree/outdegree centralization for the graph?

Answer (score 0):

This answer has been taken from a Google Groups on the issue (in the context of using R) that helps clarify the maths taken along with the above answer:

> Freeman's approach measures "the average difference in centrality 
>   between the most central actor and all others".
>
> This 'centralization' is exactly captured in the mathematical  formula
>
> sum(max(x)-x)/(length(x)-1)
>
> x refers to any centrality measure! That is, if you want to calculate 
>   the degree centralization of a network, x has simply to capture the 
>   vector of all degree values in the network. To compare various 
>   centralization measures, it is best to use standardized centrality 
>   measures, i.e. the centrality values should always be smaller than 1 
>   (best position in any possible network) and greater than 0 (worst 
>   position)... if you do so, the centralization will also be in the 
>   range of [0,1].
>
> For degree, e.g., the 'best position' is to have an edge to all other 
>   nodes (i.e. incident edges = number of nodes minus 1) and the 'worst 
>   position' is to have no incident edge at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for finding the network in degree centralization. The following is the function definition.

```py
def in_degree_centralization(G):
    centralities=nx.in_degree_centrality(G)
    max_val=max(bcc.values())
    summ=0
    for i in bcc.values():
        cc= max_val-i
        summ=summ+cc
    normalization_factor=(len(G.nodes())-1)*(len(G.nodes())-2)
    return summ/normalization_factor
```

revoke the same function by passing the graph G as parameter i.e `in_degree_centralization(graph)`